# Comparing 2 float values in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have a float `variable-field1` in 2 `tables-table1` & `table2`. When I query the table and check the values of the field both look identical but when I find their difference it gives a difference instead of zero.

```
Field1(Table1) value---84.4660194174757
Field2(Table2) value---84.4660194174757

Differnce---1.4210854715202E-14
```

Why would I get this problem?

Comment: Well, why are you using `FLOAT` instead of `DECIMAL`?

Comment: The data is exported from a spreadsheet and sqlserver automatically detects it with FLOAT..

Comment: `FLOAT` is an approximate datatype, so this kind of difference can be expected

Answer (score 29):

- Use [`ROUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175003.aspx) to limit the decimal places
- Use `ABS(value1-value2) < 0.00001` with some suitable value
- Don't use float

Comment: Are you one of the founders of this site? I ask because your rep is so high!

Comment: It's worth noting that `Round` of a `float` returns a `float`, so the result remains an approximate numeric type. Another alternative is to `cast` or `convert` to an exact numeric type, e.g. [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), for the calculation. In any event the user needs to be aware of the _precision_ and _scale_ needed to represent values in their problem domain.

Comment: Is there a way to INSERT/SELECT the 4 binary bytes of a float?  Work with it losslessly?  I understand using @parameters is lossless.